# Problem in MySQL cluster when using two clusters

Tags: mysql, replication, clustering, mysql-cluster

I have a master-slave MySQL Cluster 1 which is two way. It is working fine.
I have another MySQL master-slave Cluster 2 where data is coming from Cluster 1 master to Cluster 2 master. It is also working fine except the part where data is not replicated to slave in Cluster 2.

This setup is shown in diagram below. The problem part is shown in RED color i.e. it is not working.

Is this kind of setup even possible and if yes then how can I make it work?[image]

Comment: Could you define "not working"?

Comment: Data is not replicated to slave in cluster 2.

Comment: Is this NDB Clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from the diagram that this is not in fact MySQL Cluster (NDB) but rather the informal sense of the word "cluster."

This should be fine as long as you don't intend to write to M2 or S2, or if you do, that the writes are exclusively to schemas and tables that do not exist on M1.

There are three probable causes:

- You didn't enable `log_slave_updates` on both M1 and M2.  Without this option, incoming events don't propagate outward.
- You haven't given each server a unique `server_id`.
- You're doing replication filtering (rarely a good idea) and its configuration is being interpreted differently than you expect.